# Use of Backslash character causes error in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to create a variable using to following command -

```
REPLACEMENT_STRING="s/\(\"version\"[ ]*:[ ]*\".+test-foo\.)[0-9]+\"/\1${BUILD_NUMBER}\"/g"
```

I get the following error -

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 109: unexpected char: '\' @ line 109, column 23.
   REPLACEMENT_STRING="s/\(\"version\"[ ]*:[ ]*\".+test-foo\.)[0-9]+\"/\1${BUILD_NUMBER}\"/g"


1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:139)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:330)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Any usage of the backslash character (except as an escape character to quotes) causes this error. Is this an issue in Jenkins or am I doing something wrong here?

Jenkins ver. 2.121.1

Comment: As in many program languages the backslash in groovy is an escape character, too. If you want to have it part of the string you need to put two \\ there.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape backslash by simply using two backslashes instead of one. So just replace all instances of `\` with `\\` in your file.

Comment: My problem is the \ itself was an escape char , but for some reason it wasn't treated as an escape, as expected...

Comment: I used it in `"pattern": "(.*\.zip|.*\.war|.*\.pom)"`  regexp